# Expert opinions on brewing beer from bread (If an expert were to use this method)

Tags: beer, fermentation

I found this link the other day on how to make beer from stale bread. It seems like it is legitimately working, but at the same time, it doesn't seem very clear on it's alcohol adjustments. My goal is to make a 12% beer out of household ingredients. If anyone has any tips to help me successfully brew a batch (Doesn't have to be great beer. I don't expect New York strip out of pig intestines) please let me know. Also, on the site's alcohol adjustments, it's not clear or consistent with the original recipe, e.g. for the original, it says use a breathable cloth and let sit 1-2 days, where as on the adjustment, it says to use an airlock and let it sit 6-7 after fermentation begins. Than both say strain out the solids. If anyone can clear the air for me so I know what to do, I would greatly appreciate it!

http://sites.google.com/site/yankeeharp/breadbeer

Comment: This site is geared around specific questions and answers. As it is, it's unclear what your question is. If you have a specific question you need help with, then please post it.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is [Kvass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvass), which is brewed using rye bread as a base.   A traditional one is not going to be particularly alcoholic, though (on the order of ginger beer).

[Neo-Kvass from The Mad Fermentationist](http://www.themadfermentationist.com/2007/07/neo-kvass.html)  (This guy has logged making a couple of other ones, too, which might be up your alley, though)

Answer (score 0):

whether or not you use an airlock or a breathable cloth you are going to end up with a myriad of whatever yeasts are on that stale bread. 
The only reason to use an airlock would be if you boiled the bread to create a wort( or something like it), and then pitched yeast to it.